# UIView is being hidden by tableview sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sectionheader

I created a `UIView` which I want to display over my `UITableView`.

I add it by adding to the current view: `[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];`

When I `scroll` the `section headers` will hover over top of this `view`.

Am I adding the `view` over table correctly or should I be adding it to a different `view`?

Comment: Why add it 'over' the table rather than 'below' the table?

Comment: Do you want your view to scroll with the table view rows, or do you want your view to remain in a fixed position on the screen when the table view scrolls?

Comment: No, I want the view to stay fixed in position - essentially I want to always display an ad banner over the view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you trie the following?

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.adBanner aboveSubview:yourTableview];
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  I was already calling the bring to front method and it has similar results..

Answer (score 0):

Import quartzCore and set z-index of table view to -100 as given code below:-

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[tableView.layer setZPosition:-100];
```